# LocalBusiness with multiple locations on same page

Tags: url, schema.org, microdata

I am trying to add local business Schema.org markup on a website. 
I have one concern, there are around 10 different locations for the business and all those locations are on 1 page, that means they don't have a dedicated page for each location, now while adding Schema.org markup it requires URL for a particular location.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <span itemprop="name"><a href="/xyz">anchor-text <!-- I am confused here what URL to add for a particular location which doesn't have a dedicated page --></a></span>
  <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">example</span>
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">example</span>
    <span itemprop="addressRegion">example</span>
    <span itemprop="postalCode">expamle</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, I am thinking to either add homepage URL (`example.com`) for every location schema or add the `example.com/locations.html` URL where the list of locations resides currently or just skip the URL part completely in the markup.

Comment: How do you add a second location? Another `address` property with `PostalAddress` value? or another `LocalBusiness`?

Comment: Yes, another localbusiness schema, but it will have a different address ofcourse and different URL

Comment: Okay, and what/who requires the URL ("while adding Schema.org markup it requires URL for a particular location")? If I test the snippet from your question in Google’s SDTT, it reports no errors/warnings.

Comment: Hi @unor, in case someone has same question, I actually stumbled across a post which talks about the same thing I posted. https://www.odddogmedia.com/seo-blog/use-schema-markup-optimize-multiple-locations/  There is no need to have different URLs, just 1 site URL and then markup different locations in that. Thanks.